# AJAX with PHP self-submitting form and validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've been learning PHP via the book "PHP Solutions" by David Powers, which has a contact form with basic validation/error handling and input sanitization I would like to use without refreshing the page.

I'm testing this locally with XAMPP, and using the php form itself works perfectly: error messages display correctly, and if the form is successfully submitted, a thank you page is displayed and the form is delivered as an email to my test email address.

Now I need the form to submit and display error messages with AJAX. I've read many posts on accomplishing this, but I've been unsuccessful in implementing this. I've tried both the jQuery $.ajax and $.post methods - if the fields are all filled, the success message displays, but the message is not sent.

My guess is that javascript and php arrays are structured differently, but don't know how to reconcile this. I'm not even sure what the php processing scripts are getting/sending, if anything. How can I get this form to submit without refreshing the page, but still using the php scripts for server-side validation?

To simplify, I've stripped everything else from my page (and put all files in the same folder), except for the form: php, html, and the jQuery/AJAX I can't figure out.

Hope this makes sense. My 4 files:

mySite.js (the jQuery/AJAX I'm having trouble with...):

```
mySite = {

    jsFormSubmission : function() {
        $("#feedback").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var errorMsg = "<p class=\"errorBox\">Please fix the item(s) indicated.</p>";
            var successMsg = "<p class=\"messageBox\">Thanks for the submission, your message has been sent.</p>";

            var myObject = {
                name : $("#name").val(),
                email : $("#email").val(),
                comments : $("#comments").val()
            };

            var ajaxData = JSON.stringify(myObject);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'form.php',
                data: ajaxData,
                success: function(data){
                    $(".formResult").html(successMsg);
                },
                error: function(http) {
                    $(".formResult").html(errorMsg);
                    alert(http.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    }

};
```

The form (contact.php):

```
<?php include("form.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=" mySite.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            mySite.jsFormSubmission();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="contact">

        <p class="formResult"></p>

        <?php $errorForm = (($_POST && $suspect) || ($_POST && isset($errors['mailfail'])));
              $errorTag = $missing || $errors;
              if ($errorForm || $errorTag) { ?>

        <p class="errorBox">
        <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($errorForm) { ?>
                Sorry, your message could not be sent. Please try again later.
                <?php  } elseif ($errorTag) { ?>
                Please fix the item(s) indicated.
            <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($errorForm || $errorTag) { ?>
        </p>
        <?php } ?>

        <form id="feedback" method="post" action="">

            <div class="tag">
                <label id="lblName" for="name">Name: 
                <?php if ($missing && in_array('name', $missing)) { ?>
                    <span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">Please enter your name</span>
                <?php } ?>
                </label>
                <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="formbox"
                <?php if ($missing || $errors) {
                    echo 'value="' . htmlentities($name, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '"';
                } ?>>
            </div>

            <div class="tag">
                <label id="lblEmail" for="email">Email: 
                <?php if ($missing && in_array('email', $missing)) { ?>
                    <span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">Please enter your email address</span>
                <?php } elseif (isset($errors['email'])) { ?>
                    <span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">Invalid email address</span>
                <?php } ?>
                </label>
                <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="formbox"
                <?php if ($missing || $errors) {
                    echo 'value="' . htmlentities($email, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '"';
                } ?>>
            </div>

            <div class="tag">
                <label id="lblComments" for="comments">Comments: 
                <?php if ($missing && in_array('comments', $missing)) { ?>
                    <span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">Please enter your message</span>
                <?php } ?>
                </label>
                <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="60" rows="8"><?php 
                    if ($missing || $errors) {
                        echo htmlentities($comments, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
                    } ?></textarea>
            </div>

            <p>
                <input name="send" id="send" type="submit" value="Send message">
            </p>

        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

form.php (included at top of contact.php):

```
<?php 
$name = '';
$email = '';
$comments = '';
$required = '';
$errors = array();
$missing = array();
// check if the form has been submitted
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    //email processing script
    $to = 'johntest2@localhost';
    $subject = 'Website contact form';
    //list expected fields
    $expected = array('name', 'email', 'comments');
    // set required fields
    $required = array('name', 'email', 'comments');
    $headers = "From: Website Contact Test<johntest1@localhost>\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';

    require('processmail.php');
    if ($mailSent) {
        header("Location: thankYou.php#main");
        $messageConfirm = true;
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

processmail.php (validation scripts - included in form.php):

```
<?php

$suspect = false;
$pattern = '/Content-Type:|Bcc:|Cc:/i';

// function to check for suspect phrases
function isSuspect($val, $pattern, &$suspect) {
    if (is_array($val)) {
        foreach ($val as $item) {
            isSuspect($item, $pattern, $suspect);
        }
    } else {
        if (preg_match($pattern, $val)) {
            $suspect = true;
        }
    }
}
isSuspect($_POST, $pattern, $suspect);

if (!$suspect) {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $temp = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);
        if (empty($temp) && in_array($key, $required)) {
            $missing[] = $key;
        } elseif (in_array($key, $expected)) {
            ${$key} = $temp;
        }
    }
}

// validate the user's email
if (!$suspect && !empty($email)) {
    $validemail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if ($validemail) {
        $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: $validemail";
    } else {
            $errors['email'] = true;
    }
}

$mailSent = false;

if (!$suspect && !$missing && !$errors) {

    // initialize the $message variable
    $message = '';
    foreach($expected as $item) {
        if (isset(${$item}) && !empty(${$item})) {
            $val = ${$item};
        } else {
            $val = 'Not selected';
        }
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $val = implode(', ', $val);
        }
        $item = str_replace(array('_', '-'), ' ', $item);
        $message .= ucfirst($item).": $val\r\n\r\n";
    }

    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);

    $mailSent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if (!$mailSent) {
        $errors['mailfail'] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `data: '$("#feedback").serializeArray();',` is incorrect. that'll submit the JS code as a string, not the output of a serialize call - the code is never seen as anything other than a string. You've also a stray `'` above that line, throwing off everything else.

Comment: Ah, yes, I accidentally deleted that ' when I posted this. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: And I see your point about data: '' being a string. I replaced the variable I was using to try and shorten my code up for posting. If I remove the apostrophes and semicolon, so it reads data: $("#feedback").serializeArray(), I'm still not able to submit with ajax.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways that you can get the error to display from the PHP side. You can throw an exception, which I wouldn't recommend, or use a header:

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
```

In your AJAX call, use the jQuery error callback:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: //url,
    data: //data,
    success: function (data) { //show success },
    error: function () { //display code here } 
});
```

You can also return the error in the body of the error message from the PHP side, and strip that from the body in your error callback.

PHP:

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
echo 'Your error message';
```

JavaScript:

```
error: function(http) {
   // show http.responseText;
}
```

Also, for your form submission, pack your data into a object, and then serialize it. So:

```
var myObject = {
    property1 : 'string',
    property2 : [ 'array' ]
};

var ajaxData = JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

Comment: Ok, so in myObject, I'll want to use this format for each of my fields, then pass the ajaxData variable to the data setting, like: $.ajax({data:ajaxData});? Or do I also need to serialize the ajaxData var? I haven't worked with json before, will look into it.
And thanks for your help! I'll try this out later today when I get home from work.

Comment: jQuery should do it for you, so you can pass in the object raw (without using JSON.stringify). I can't remember if PHP will automatically input the JSON array as a PHP array. I think it does, but I'm not in a position to test that right now.

Comment: Using the Object in JavaScript eliminates a lot of extra work on your end putting the variables into an acceptable format. If you're using a form, you can also use $('#myform').serialize() to get the data easier, but I find it a better practice to use an object.

Comment: I've updated my jQuery to use your suggestion. And the php header you showed me works great for testing any error output on the page; thanks for that, I used it to test the jqery error message.

But when I remove the header and try using the jq ajax method and data object, as you suggested, it always returns successful, even if no fields are filled. And no email is sent, so I don't think the php is doing anything with the ajaxData that's sent.

I can figure out error displays and such later, but how can I get this so the email is sent using the ajax method?

Comment: If you're using Chrome or Safari, use the developer tools in it to see what is being sent to the server, or use a console.log() in your JavaScript to see what is being inputted. It looks like none of your data is being passed. I would switch in between seeing what your client sends to the server and using 'echo' or 'print_r' in PHP to show what was sent. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: Looking at the firebug console, it does look like it's at least posting data with ajax - POST http://localhost/uploadTest/form.php, under the source section in the 'POST' tab:
{"name":"John M","email":"johntest@yahoo.com","comments":"Contact form ajax test message"} - same data under the 'JSON' section.

Do I need to add something to my form.php file for the JSON string that's being posted? I don't understand why the string sent with the .ajax() method isn't working with my php file.

Comment: Grab your data from using `$content = file_get_contents('php://input');`

You'll have to parse it using `json_decode($content);` which will return it as an associative array, e.g. `$email = $json['email']`.

The reason you're not getting the data right now is because the end server won't find it in the $_POST array. The POST data is being sent in the post body. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I've been swamped lately & couldn't get back at this until this past weekend.
I'm having trouble understanding how to implement your json_decode suggestion. Do I need to use this **instead** of the 'if (isset($_POST['send'])) {} ' statement in my form.php? I've tried adding your suggestion to this, but I'm not having much luck getting the ajax function to do anything. I shouldn't have to replace anything that would prevent the validation from working if js is disabled, right?

Comment: If you also know of any good tutorials that might help me understand this, that would be a welcome addition. And thanks for taking the time to go through all my code above and try helping me with this.